# Enable Vuetify 3 v-data-table-server loading progress bar colors and row hover

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I couldn't enable theme colors in data tables. It works fine on Vuetify 2.0, but I'm using Vuetify > 3.0 and it's not working.

Here is a basic example.

Vuetify.js

```
// Styles
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "vuetify/styles";

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as labs from "vuetify/labs/components";

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    ...labs,
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: "#1867C0",
          secondary: "#5CBBF6",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

App.vue

```
<v-data-table-server :headers="headers" :items="items" :loading="true">
</v-data-table-server>
```

Theme color does not work.

[image: Theme color does not work]

Also row hover does not work.

[image: Also row hover does not work]

Here is the full source code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/olomadev/testvuetify/main?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clf58w81k0007g3ivgaju5hve%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FMyDataTable.vue%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clfatyw8u00193n6lurpu8yc0%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf58wd2t004w3n6k6wxjicy5%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf58wc49002r3n6k4urlqh1q%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (Vuetify 3.1.9), you can set the color of the progress bar in `v-data-table-server` by setting the `:loading` property to a color name (instead of `true`):

```
const loadItems = async (options) => {
  loading.value = 'primary'
  serverItems.value = await loadData(options)
  loading.value = false
}
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: "#c6f714",
          secondary: "#04d9ff",
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
const app = {
  setup(){
    const loading = ref(false)
    const serverItems = ref([{id: 1, name: 'name 1'}])
    setInterval(() => loading.value = ['primary', 'secondary', '#7d12ff'][Math.random() * 3 |0], 500)
    
    return {
      itemsPerPage: ref(2),
      headers: [{key: 'id', title: 'ID'},{key: 'name', title: 'Name'}],
      totalItems: 42,
      serverItems,
      loading
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.v-theme--light.v-data-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content):not(.v-data-table__empty-wrapper) > td {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table-server
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :headers="headers"
    :items-length="totalItems"
    :items="serverItems"
    :loading="loading"
    item-title="name"
    item-value="name"
  ></v-data-table-server>
  
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.9/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
```

As to row hover, yes, it does not seem to be implemented yet, at least I can't find it in the sources. The adjusted version of Vuetify 2 CSS class would be:

```css
.v-theme--light.v-data-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody
> tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content):not(.v-data-table__empty-wrapper) 
> td {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Not sure if the `:not` classes still work as intended.

Comment: it works thanks.  Do you know how can i do row hover table ?

Comment: @ErsinGüvenç Probably CSS like `..v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr:hover > td{
background: green;
}` suffices, but I added the adjusted Vuetify 2 hover class to the answer.

Comment: in vue3, how do I set/unset color of specific row (index) in a datatable, when user presses a button?

Comment: @tunafish24 In v2, there was a `cellClass` property in `headers` which you could use for that, but it is not (yet) available in v3. For the moment, your best bet is probably to use regular [selection](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/selection/) with checkboxes

Comment: @MoritzRingler Actually, what I need to do is that if user clicks on a cell then to open a modal with detailed info about data in that cell, and highlight the entire row in datatable, so that user knows which row the modal corresponds to. And when user closes the modal to remove row highlighting. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Oh, I meant the [`:item-class` ](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-item-class) property, not `cellClass`. Same story though, it is not (yet) available in v3 (there is an [open issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16991) though). You can open the modal using the `@click:row` event, but for the highlight, you have to either wait for `:item-class` in a future version, use the click event to set the style with direct DOM manipulation, or override the `item` slot with a custom. None of which is ideal, but I don't think there is a better solution at the moment.